# Unity - Vuforia: Detect the loss of a ground plane?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

The goal is to have a button which is *interactable if a ground plane is currently detected* and gets *not interactable if the ground plane was lost*.

The default Vuforia `Plane Finder Behaviour`fires an event `OnAutomaticHitTest` if a plane was found. 
But is there an equivalent event if a plane gets lost? Or has someone already implemented a similar solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to answer my own question. I looked into the official Vuforia ground plane demo scene and obviously there is no better solution as to check if the event `OnAutomaticHitTest` was fired this frame or not. If so a plane is currently detected - if not ... well than not. Period.

Comment: for me it gets fired each single frame, am I missing something

Comment: it worked when using a real device, thanks for the great answer